# Graph API get Reviewer Img inside Ratings call

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, python-3.x

i'm working with the Facebook Graph API,currently i use the API call below to get the ratings.

What i want to do is, attach the user-image to "from". It should work the same way as the comments.summary(true). Anyone got any ideas? Or has done it?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/+page_id+'/ratings?limit=5&fields=open_graph_story'
```

Here is the source where i got the idea

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, in order to do that you have to make a nested request. Then it is possible to add fields. In this case.

```
/ratings?limit=5&fields=reviewer.limit(5){id, name,picture},open_graph_story
```